# mysql select rows that have a same value as the last entered row

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join

I have created a database that adds products to a basket/cart table.

What I want to do is check what was the last item added, and count how many times it item exists in the same table.

Say the table is called "basket" and the column is product.

e.g:
cartid, product , user , date
1 , 50, bob , 2016-2-20 00:48:21
2 , 40, bob , 2016-2-20 00:48:23
3 , 50, bob , 2016-2-20 00:48:24
4 , 30, bob , 2016-2-20 00:48:25
5 , 40, bob , 2016-2-20 00:48:27

so in the above example, the last product is 40, and it occurs 2 times...

I was wondering if inner join to the same table is allowed.

Comment: What your expected output ?

Comment: the expected output would be 40 | 2 (product and the count), to complicate this: i want to use a where comment to narrow it down to the user (but i think i can handle that bit)

Comment: you can check my answer with demo that you want

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. all working.

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product,
       count(product) AS total
FROM basket
WHERE `user` like 'bob' AND product =
    (SELECT product
     FROM basket b
     ORDER BY cartid DESC LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY product
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dea8ac/1)**

Comment: Thanks. looks like i won't be able to add the where user = "bob" bit... (checking against a php server variable...  I checked it against the real db and your query is correct as it stands. it did select the last product ever added to the db and how many times it occurs.